# click on hyperlinks in unit testing using protactor in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I am new in unit testing in angularjs. I read the tutorial from:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md.

I want to click on hyperlink but i dont know how can i achieve this.

Here is my code:

```
<li ng-repeat="menu in sidebarLinks" ng-if="menu.visible == true " ng-class="{active: isActive('/{{menu.action}}')}">
                    <a ng-href="#/{{menu.action}}" title="{{menu.name}}" ng-click="loadSubmenus(menu.action)"  ng-class="{active: isActive('/{{menu.action}}')}">
                        <div class="icon {{menu.icon}}" ng-class="{active: isActive('/{{menu.action}}')}"></div> 
                           <span>{{menu.name}} </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
```

In unit testing:

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
    browser.driver.get('https://localhost:8443/login.html');

browser.driver.findElement(by.id('name')).sendKeys('test');
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('test');
browser.driver.findElement(by.id('login')).click();

});
```

After login url is  https://localhost:8443/#/dash

After click on link url should be https://localhost:8443/#/hypera

Comment: We need more information about your HTML than you're giving. There's nothing in there with your id's, so I can't tell you how to get the elements for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since your links won't work for anyone else because you're running it locally on your machine, I can only tell you the best way to do it.

If you're dealing with hyperlinks, you need to get the element that you've set with 'login'. I'm not seeing it in your HTML snippet so I can't give you the correct path.

If it was a basic hyperlink, you could find it easily by using something like:

```
element(by.linkText('login')).click()
```

If your login button's text is indeed 'login'. If it is something else, like a button, you'll need to find the exact element and it will look like:

```
element(by.css('span[class="login"]')).click()
```

If your login button is under a 'span' tag in your HTML page.